# Authentication error with Sharepoint API Python Office365 Rest API library

Tags: python, api, sharepoint, office365api, sharepoint-api

I am trying to connect to Sharepoint using the following code. It was working previously however it has suddenly stopped working, and is now showing the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Documents\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\saml_token_provider.py", line 67, in get_authentication_cookie
return 'FedAuth=' + self.FedAuth + '; rtFa=' + self.rtFa
```

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

```
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
```

if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):

```
print("Authentication with SharePoint was successful: {0}".format(
        ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password)))

ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print "SharePoint Site: {0}".format(web.properties['Title'])
```

else:
    print ctx_auth.get_last_error()

It fails on this line:

```
ctx.execute_query()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using sharepy library as an alternative solution in connecting to Sharepoint.
Use pip install sharepy to install the module.

```
import sharepy
from sharepy import connect
from sharepy import SharePointSession

server='youraccount.sharepoint.com'
user='username@domain.com'
password='password'

s = sharepy.connect(server,user,password) 

# Example request to Sharepoint
headers = {'accept': 'application/atom+json'} #json can be changed to xml
r = s.get("https://youraccount.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('path_to_your_folder/')/Files", headers=headers)
```

It should print out the following on successful authentication:

> Requesting security token...Requesting access cookie... Authentication successful

Comment: I keep getting this error: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

Comment: It throws an error while connecting: `sharepy.errors.AuthError: Unknown authentication error`

Comment: I get the same error, any solution yet !!! @Shubham

Comment: @YaserSakkaf Yeah, you can generate a client ID and client secret then use that for authentication.